# Вывести число в бухгалтерском формате

Tags: java

Например, число `20023143` должно быть выведено как `20 023 143`

```
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print(random.nextInt(10));
    }
```

Comment: А где в показанном коде собственно число `20023143`?

Answer (score 0):

Сделать это можно с помощью [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) и [DecimalFormatSymbols](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html). Сначала создадим объект DecimalFormatSymbols и укажем, что в качестве разделителя мы хотим использовать пробел:

```java
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
```

Далее создадим объект DecimalFormat, используя ранее созданный DecimalFormatSymbols:

```java
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###", symbols);
```

Теперь форматируем произвольный integer так:

```java
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(integer));
```

Например, для максимального возможного integer вывод будет такой:

```
"2 147 483 647"
```

---

Второй способ — не использовать DecimalFormatSymbols, а задать [локаль по умолчанию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault-java.util.Locale-). Например, во французской локали в качестве разделителя будет использоваться [неразрывный пробел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB):

```java
Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRANCE);
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(integer));
```

Результат:

```
"2 147 483 647"
```

Обратите внимание, что в отличие от первого варианта, здесь используются неразрывные пробелы.

Comment: Спасибо. Но и без строки symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' '); все работает. Почему так?

Comment: Если явно не выставить разделитель группы, то будет использоваться значение в зависимости от локали. Если локаль `Locale.US`, то это запятая, а если `Locale.GERMANY`, то точка. Во французской локали будет неразрывный пробел, обновил ответ, добавил второй способ.